# criteria of convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am not sure which of the criteria for convergence (divergence, respectively) of series to use for $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}}$. Thank you.

Comment: Use the integral test followed by the change of variable $x = \ln(t)$

Comment: Hint: Prove that $(\ln n)^{\ln n}\geqslant n^2$ for every $n$ large enough (that is, $n\geqslant e^{e^2}$).

Answer (score 0):

Using integral test and subbing $lnx=t$ we need to investigate the convergence of $\int(\frac{e}{t})^tdt$ and for $t>3$ the integral (integrating from 3 to infinity) is less than $\int(\frac{e}{3})^tdt$ which is convergent by geometric series.

Comment: A downvote without a reason? I wonder why...